# weak convergence + bounded second moment implies convergence of the moment?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\{\mu_N\}$ be a sequence of random measures which converges almost surely in the weak sense to a deterministic measure $\mu$ with impact support.

The weak convergence does not necessarily imply the convergence of the moments. But, my question is that, if we add the assumption that the second moment of $\mu_N$ is almost surely bounded, can we deduce that the second moment of $\{\mu_N\}$ converges to the second moment of $\mu$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\mu_N$ assigns mass $1/(2N^2)$ to each of $\pm N$ and mass $1-1/N^2$ to $0$. Then $\mu_N$ (which have second moment equal to $1$) converge weakly to the dirac measure at $0$.

Comment: What if we add the assumption that the support is almost surely bounded? Do we have the result or not?

Comment: Yes, since in that case $x^2$ is a bounded continuous function on the support.